# Simulate a real browser in curl

Tags: php, curl

for some time I have been trying to write the ideal browser simulations, for this purpose I wrote a script that to some extent simulates the browser and works correctly on many pages with ssl. Recently during the test site pornhub.com and wikipedia.com encountered a strange error in my script, just for pornhub after a few page reloads shows the status of header "Loading .. Content-length: 1456" and the number of loaded data changes in real time on smaller and larger values. I have a question for already very experienced and professional programmers: Have you met with such a situation, if so you have any hints or corrections for my script ?.

I post my code (test for wikipedia). If you fire it on 3 browser tabs and you will refresh, you will get an error.

```
<?php 
function curl($url)
{

    $headers = [
        'Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'
    ];
    $cookie = 'cookie.txt'; 
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.wikipedia.org');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
    if (!file_exists($cookie)){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    }else{     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    }
    $c = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $c;
}

echo curl('https://www.wikipedia.org');
?>
```

Comment: May be a bit critical to use this site as the example. Can't you reproduce the problem with Wikipedia or any other *harmless* site?

Comment: Yes. I changed the example to Wikipedia

Comment: Besides, verify peer and verify host are off so anyone using this script could be exposed to man in the middle attacks.

Comment: You can't simulate client-side evaluation of Javascript using curl alone.  Many sites will depend on JS to function properly, and will even perform browser checks that will prevent purely HTTP clients like curl/wget from being able to use the site.  Check out Selenium.